# How do I validate an x-www-form-urlencoded string without using its contents or header

Tags: python, json, x-www-form-urlencoded

I understand that I can validate json as such:

```
import json

jsondump = json.dumps(jsonstring)

if json.loads(jsondump):
    print("Valid")
else:
    ("no")
```

I am trying to distinguish between a JSON string and an x-www-form-urlencoded string. I would like to do this without using the content of the string or check if keys are present to identify this.

I know that the MIME type of a file can be used to identify the content type however, I am not using file as input but rather a string from a variable.

My question is: Can I identify if the content type is x-www-form-urlencoded without using the contents of the string or using a content-type header?

Answer (score 1):

Without checking the `Content-Type` header in the response, it could be hard to validate that the response data is a JSON string rather than a *x-www-form-urlencoded* string.

Note that there is nothing wrong with how you were validating the data; using `json.loads` to confirm that the JSON string is valid seems a good idea as any to me.

However, if you *are* sure that a server only responds back with either a **valid** JSON string or *x-www-form-urlencoded* data, then you probably could simplify this check a little in the interests of time (and performance, to some degree) as shown below.

Essentially here, instead of loading the whole JSON string into memory via `json.loads`, we only check the start character which marks the beginning of a valid JSON string.

```py
response_string = '  [{"test": "value"}] '

trimmed = response_string.lstrip()
is_json_string = trimmed.startswith(('[', '{'))

print(is_json_string)  # True
```

Comment: Thank you. My reasoning behind not using the Content-Type header is that I can't rely on the client/introducer to post data with the header. So I was wondering if there was a method to do this